# Sending different lines of txt to different objects

Tags: java, aggregation

Im working on an aggregation lab and basically the problem that I am having is that in my txt file the first line of the text file show a person and their information and on the next two lines shows their animals information. I was able to make an object for the person but when I try to sent the next line to the animal object I keep getting a java.util.noSuchElementsExceptions error and I dont know why. Can somebody please help me out.

---

The text file looks like this:

Morely,Robert,123 Anywhere Street,15396,4,234.56,2

Bubba,Bulldog,58,4-15-2010,6-14-2011

Lucy,Bulldog,49,4-15-2010,6-14-2011

Wilder,John,457 Somewhere Road,78214,3,124.53,1

Ralph,Cat,12,01-16-2011,04-21-2012

---

```
Person p;
Animal a;

int number;
String line;
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner (new File("C://clientdata.txt"));
String animal;
int j;
j = 0;
String []Person =new String[j];
 while (fileInput.hasNext())
 {
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(fileInput.nextLine(), ",");
   p = new Person();
   p.setFirstName (st.nextToken());
   p.setLastName(st.nextToken());
   p.setAddress(st.nextToken());
   p.setClientID(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
   p.setVisits(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
   p.setBalance(Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken()));
   p.setNumPets(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
   number = p.getNumPets();
   System.out.println(number);

   for(int i =0; i < number; i++)
   {
    fileInput.nextLine();
    a = new Animal();
    a.setName(st.nextToken());
    a.setType(st.nextToken());
    a.setWeight(Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()));
    a.setDate(st.nextToken());
    a.setLastVisit(st.nextToken());

   }
   }
}
```

Comment: You call `fileInput.nextLine()` and ignore the value returned, then continue to call `st.nextToken()`, but there are no tokens left from the first line. Don't use `Scanner` to read the file, use `BufferedReader`. Don't use `StringTokenizer` to parse the lines, use `split()`. From javadoc: *"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead."*

Comment: Our teacher told us to input the text file this way and not use buffered reader. Im so confused at this point because all im trying to do is get the scanner to read the next line so that the information from the next line can be entered into the animal class or object.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement in the for loop should be st = new StringTokenizer(fileInput.nextLine(), ",");